# Is it possible to remove the top level key from a nested dictionary and keep the values?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, nested

Example of the nested dictionary with the keys to be removed.

```
{1: {'Email': 'JohnDoe@email.com',
     'FirstName': 'John',
     'Id': {'Value': 1},
     'LastName': 'Doe',
     'UserName': 'JohnDoe'},
 2: {'Email': 'JaneDoe@email.com',
     'FirstName': 'Jane',
     'Id': {'Value': 2},
     'LastName': 'Doe',
     'UserName': 'JaneDoe'},
 3: {'Email': 'FredDoe@email.com',
     'FirstName': 'Fred',
     'Id': {'Value': 1},
     'LastName': 'Doe',
     'UserName': 'FredDoe'}}
```

Is it possible to remove the numeric keys and save the dictionary like below?

```
   {{'Email': 'JohnDoe@email.com',
     'FirstName': 'John',
     'Id': {'Value': 1},
     'LastName': 'Doe',
     'UserName': 'JohnDoe'},
    {'Email': 'JaneDoe@email.com',
     'FirstName': 'Jane',
     'Id': {'Value': 2},
     'LastName': 'Doe',
     'UserName': 'JaneDoe'},
    {'Email': 'FredDoe@email.com',
     'FirstName': 'Fred',
     'Id': {'Value': 1},
     'LastName': 'Doe',
     'UserName': 'FredDoe'}}
```

Comment: In your expected output, shouldn't the outer container be a list? Having something like `{{1: 'a'}, {2: 'b'}, {3: 'b'}}` isn't possible since dictionaries aren't hashable.

Comment: Thanks Sean. So it sounds like I would need to convert the dictionary to a list to get the desired output? I'm trying to build a JSON file with the expected output and the original dictionary is obtained from a REST API so looking for a way to remove the numeric keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the dictionary is in a variable `d`, all you have to do is [`d.values()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values), which will give you the values of each of the `key, value` pairs from the dictionary:

```
>>> d = {1: {'Email': 'JohnDoe@email.com', 'FirstName': 'John', 'Id': {'Value': 1}, 'LastName': 'Doe', 'UserName': 'JohnDoe'}, 2: {'Email': 'JaneDoe@email.com', 'FirstName': 'Jane', 'Id': {'Value': 2}, 'LastName': 'Doe', 'UserName': 'JaneDoe'}, 3: {'Email': 'FredDoe@email.com', 'FirstName': 'Fred', 'Id': {'Value': 1}, 'LastName': 'Doe', 'UserName': 'FredDoe'}}
>>> l = list(d.values())
>>> l
[{'Email': 'JohnDoe@email.com', 'FirstName': 'John', 'Id': {'Value': 1}, 'LastName': 'Doe', 'UserName': 'JohnDoe'}, {'Email': 'JaneDoe@email.com', 'FirstName': 'Jane', 'Id': {'Value': 2}, 'LastName': 'Doe', 'UserName': 'JaneDoe'}, {'Email': 'FredDoe@email.com', 'FirstName': 'Fred', 'Id': {'Value': 1}, 'LastName': 'Doe', 'UserName': 'FredDoe'}]
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to create a dictionary that only consisted of keys rather than keys and values